# Where to put AsyncTask so that it's only started once

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

Right now I have a Timer starting an AsyncTask in a `Fragment`s `onCreate` method (with a timer interval of 1 minute). So that is not a good idea I believe because if there is a configuration change the fragment will call the onCreate method again and I will have 2 running Timer AsyncTasks right?

So I need some way to put the AsyncTask where it's only started once during the whole lifecycle of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [Countdown Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) and cancel it in `onDestroy()`. That would guarantee that you only have a single one running at any time.

As for starting it exactly only once you will have to persist that knowledge somewhere depending on your needs. Maybe storing a boolean in `onSaveInstanceState` and reading it in `onCreate()` would do the trick?

And, as @marcin_j has pointed out, AsyncTasks are executed in sequence (unless specifically started differently), so using one will block *every* other Async task in your app (like downloading stuff etc).

Comment: Maybe an easy way would be to check  if `savedInstanceState` is `null` then that would mean that it's the first time the `Fragment` is created so I start the AsyncTask in there?

Comment: The boolean approach is the better way, it's also future proof. I am not exactly sure if `savedInstanceState` is guaranteed to be not null in subsequent starts, especially if you never save anything to it.

Answer (score 4):

no need of Asynctask for simple timer, try this -

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment{
 private int currentTime;
 private void startTimer(){
  new Handler().
               postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                      @Override
                       public void run()
                       {
                        onTick();
                        startTimer(); 
                       }
                    },1000*60);
 }
 private void onTick()
 {
   currentTime++;
 }
 @Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
 {
      outState.putInt("currentTime", currentTime);
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
 }
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
 {
   currentTime=savedInstanceState.getInt("currentTime",0);
   startTimer();
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm downloading some stuff in my AsyncTask (that's why I'm using an AsyncTask).

Answer (score 0):

if there is a configuration change the activity gets destroyed and re-created so no you will not have 2 timers running

Comment: But the AsyncTask is running in a separate thread. I assumed that the AsyncTask thread would continue running even if the activity is destroyed?

Comment: The activity will be destroyed but the fragment might not be destroyed when it has `saveInstanceState` set or similar.

Comment: @PeterWarbo you are right, AsyncTask can still be running even if fragment got destoroyed during config change.